# Add custom props to a custom component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've built my own custom react-bootstrap Popover component:

```
export default class MyPopover extends Component {
  // ...
  render() {
    return (
        <Popover {...this.props} >
           // ....
        </Popover>
    );
  }
}
```

The component is rendered like so:

```
// ... my different class ...

  render() {

    const popoverExample = (
        <MyPopover id="my-first-popover" title="My Title">
          my text 
        </MyPopover >
    );

    return (
        <OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="top" overlay={popoverExample}>
          <Button>Click Me</Button>
        </OverlayTrigger>
    );
  }
```

Now, I want to add custom props to `MyPopover` component like that: 
     
           my text 
     
And to use the new props to set some things in the popover
for example -

```
    <Popover {...this.props} className={this.getClassName()}>
       {this.showTheRightText(this.props)}
    </Popover>
```

but then I get this warning in the browser:

> Warning: Unknown props `popoverType` on  tag. Remove these props from the element.

Now, I guess that I can just remove the `{...this.props}` part and insert all the original props one by one without the custom props, but In this way I lose the "fade" effect and also it's an ugly way to handle this problem. Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated answer (React v16 and older):

As of **React v16**, you can pass custom DOM attributes to a React Component. The problem/warning generated is no longer relevant. [More info](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html).

---

### Original answer (React v15):

The easiest solution here is to simply remove the extra `prop` before sending it to the `Popover` component, and there's a convenient solution for doing that.

```
export default class MyPopover extends Component {
  // ...
  render() {
    let newProps = Object.assign({}, this.props);  //shallow copy the props
    delete newProps.popoverType;  //remove the "illegal" prop from our copy.

    return (
        <Popover {...newProps} >
           // ....
        </Popover>
    );
  }
}
```

*Obviously you can (and probably should) create that variable outside your `render()` function as well.*

Basically you can send any `props` you want to *your own* component, but you'd have to "clean" it before passing it through. All `react-bootstrap` components are cleansed from "illegal" props before being passed as attributes to the DOM, however it doesn't handle any custom props that *you* may have provided, hence why you have to do your own bit of housekeeping.

React started throwing this warning as of [version 15.2.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v15.2.0). Here's what the documentation says about this:

> The unknown-prop warning will fire if you attempt to render a DOM element with a prop that is not recognized by React as a legal DOM attribute/property. You should ensure that your DOM elements do not have spurious props floating around.
>
> [...]
>
> To fix this, composite components should "consume" any prop that is intended for the composite component and not intended for the child component.

*For further reading, check [**this page**](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html) from the official react site.*