# How can I pass a locally created function and variable as props in a component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a button component (a dumb component) and I would like to have an optional animation attached to it, and pass that animation down in props, to be triggered by a boolean value of another prop. I keep getting errors on trying to pass both. `Unknown prop 'ripple' on <button> tag. Remove this prop from the element.`

```
const Button = (props) => {
{propOne, propTwo, ripple, ...remainingProps} = props

 function coolAnimation () {
  // cool ripple effect code
 }

  return (
    <button
      className={css( styles.button, secondary && styles.secondary)}
      {...remainingProps}
      ripple={false}
      animation={coolAnimation}
    >
      {label}
      {props.children}
    </button>
  )
}

export default Button
```

I have also tried creating the component as a class (in case it mattered):

```
class Button extends React.Component {
{propOne, propTwo, ripple, ...remainingProps} = props

  _coolAnimation () {
   // cool ripple effect code
  }

 render() {
  return (
    <button
      className={css( styles.button, secondary && styles.secondary)}
      {...remainingProps}
      ripple={false}
      animation={coolAnimation}
    >
      {label}
      {props.children}
    </button>
  )
 }
}

export default Button
```

I suspect I can't just add `ripple` into the const that is deconstructing the `props` object because it does not already exist on the object being deconstructed there. I have tried just extending the object using `this.props.ripple = false` and got an error saying the object is not extendable.

How do I properly add and pass these as props?

if it helps, ideally I would be able to do this: `<Button ripple={true} onClick={ripple && coolAnimation}></Button>` or something similar and have instances of the button that use the ripple animation and others that do not.

**UPDATE:**

So following the provided guide, I have a separate (parent) component that now takes in the Button component:

```
class RippleButton extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    _animateRipple(e) {
     // create animation            
    } 

    render() {
        const {children} = this.props
        return (
            <Button 
                className={css(wrapperStyle.rippleWrapper)}
                animation={this._animateRipple}
                ripple={false}
            >
          {children}
            </Button>
        )       
    }
}

export default RippleButton
```

And I have the child Button component which is only rendering the html button:

```
const Button = props => {
  const { label, secondary, ...remainingProps } = props

  return (
    <button
      className={ css(
        styles.button,
        secondary && styles.secondary) }
      {...remainingProps}
    >
      {label}
      {props.children}
    </button>
  )
}

Button.PropTypes = {
  label: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  secondary: React.PropTypes.bool,
}

export default Button
```

but I am still getting the same error `Unknown props`animation`,`ripple`on <button> tag` even though I am passing them from the parent Component, into the Button component (not the button tag directly as I was before)...thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The issue

The problem here is that you are trying to render an **HTML element** with an invalid attributes, such as the `ripple` attribute. React doesn't like this, and as of version 15.0.2 React will throw a warning about this in the console (as you've noticed).

It's also important to understand the difference between `<button foo="bar" />` and `<Button foo="bar" />`. The former creates an HTML element with an **attribute** of `foo`, whereas the latter calls React component to be rendered and passes a **prop** of `foo`.

With that said, you can create *any* React component you want and pass *any* data you want with props. However HTML elements cannot take *any* attribute you want.

---

#### Solution

To fix the warning you're having you should take a look at [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40280490/2030321) that I answered the other day. It also explains the problem of "custom props" in more detail than what I've done above.

If you *really* want a custom html *attribute*, you can use `data-` followed by the name of your attribute that you want. For example:

```
<button data-ripple="false">My button</button>
```

This is a valid html element and so is the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're getting a few patterns wrong here--you might want to consider hitting-up a good `React` tutorial. It'll take some time, but will save you tremendous amounts of frustration longer-term.

As to your question, a few points:

first, the error you're getting is because you're assigning attributes on a regular `html` element, not a `React component`. The `tag names` are case sensitive, so `<button> !== <Button>`

second, you're skipping a few steps in achieving your goal. Unfortunately it's not as simple as just declaring an animation--the component has to be told when to animate, what to animate, etc. etc.

Here's a simple example of a button that grows when `onMouseOver`. I haven't tested this, so don't take it as gospel:

```
// parent component
class ButtonParent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    isMouseOver: false
  }
  this.handleButtonHover = this.handleButtonHover.bind(this)
  }

  handleButtonHover() {
    this.setState({ isMouseOver: !this.state.isMouseOver })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button 
          handleButtonHover={this.handleButtonHover} 
          isButtonHovered={this.state.isButtonHovered}
        />
      <div>
    )
  }

// Button.jsx
const Button = (props) => {
  const {handleButtonHover, isButtonHovered, ...remainingProps} = props

  const style = {
    transform: props.ripple === true ? 'scale(1.5,1.5) : 'scale(1,1)',
    transition: 'all 0.5s ease-in',
  }

  return (
    <button
       onMouseEnter={props.handleButtonHover}
       onMouseLeave={props.handleButtonHover}
      {...remainingProps}
    >
      {label}
      {props.children}
    </button>
  )
}

export default Button
```

Do you see the pattern? the current state is held in the parent, which passes it, and a `callback` to the child. when the child sees the event, it uses the `callback`, which changes the state at the parent level, and affects (via the `style` object) button.

This type of handle event -> adjust state -> re-render pattern is critical to a `React` app, as is the use of `ternary operators` to handle events.

Comment: Yes, I am def getting my patterns a little mixed up! Probably pretty obvious I am new to React, and feeling the learning curb (I do have some great tutorials, but I am still bumping my head along the way, lol) I am going to sit here for a few mins and study your example, then try to implement it -before I come back here (I may have more questions, lol)... and thank you SO MUCH for providing an example of the proper pattern!

Comment: I marked your answer right before I saw I had the same errors with what I thought was the correct approach (I was looking at the wrong console, too many consoles and tabs open!) - I do however think I am on the right track following your example...could you check my update?

Comment: it's okay, i forgot to pass the props in the const! :)

Comment: so you're on the right track as far as patterns go--passing them down from the parent, that is. but the reason you were getting the error was because `<button>` simply doesn't have an `animate` property, so it doesn't know what to do with whatever function you're passing in.  "Animate" is a vague term, so it's hard to say what you should be doing here. The easiest way to animate in React is something like my example--to change `style` properties based on `events` and `callbacks`. That way, the only property you're passing to `button` is `style`.

Comment: well the animation I am doing is a onclick ripple effect and I am using a JS func to get the click coordinates, so it's not something I can do with CSS alone. the tricky thing is that the buttons I want to call it on have their own click events that toggle stuff...so I can't call the animate func as a click event directly in the parent component as that cancels out the click event in the render where Button is used and will call toggle...but I if i can pass it as a prop, i can combine the two onClick functions into one function above the render and then call that, i think.. still having issues

Comment: @HolyMoly i know this probably isn't what you want to hear, but it sounds like you need to spend some more time in a React tutorial. the way you're describing things suggests that there are a few key concepts you're not rock-solid on.  a `<button>` only has one onclick event. you can, however, execute as many functions as you want w/in that event. however, i'm not sure what an 'animate function' specifically does, so it's hard to say if this is the best avenue. as to getting the coordinates of the button, that's generally discouraged in React unless you truly know what you're doing.

Comment: lol, i'm not offended - I am only 2 weeks into react, I still have a lot to wrap my mind around! But this is how you learn, by getting your hands dirty, right? In this case my main issue was my patterns, as you pointed out, but I have successfully accomplished what I needed to do, and it works great! I made the click event internal to the Button, and set up a function that calls both the animation, as well as the primary function of the button (passed in as another prop). Button can also be used normally, if no props are passed to trigger the animation.

Comment: I got the coordinates with some JS, no biggie. I am new to React, but not programming in general. Thank you so much for your help btw!