# Simple React Component does not update

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component:
Somehow `DropdownMultiselect`  does not update, even though the variables changed.
**What do I wrong here?**

```
function Sidebar({chartOptions}) {
  let variables = []
  if(chartOptions){
    variables = chartOptions
  }

  return (
    <DropdownMultiselect options={variables} name="variables"/>
  )
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `useState()`? Values not bound to state probably don't trigger re-render.

Comment: Does this help? [How can I pass a locally created function and variable as props in a component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322789/how-can-i-pass-a-locally-created-function-and-variable-as-props-in-a-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mutate variable like that in React. You can use the prop directly, using `??` to handle the case where chartOptions is null or undefined :

```
function Sidebar({chartOptions}) {
  return (
    <DropdownMultiselect options={chartOptions ?? []} name="variables"/>
  )
}
```