# React - Remove prop from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to remove a prop from a child.

I have a container element which uses a property on it's children to perform some enhancements on the children. That property should be removed from the child before rendering.

```
<AsyncContainer>
   <Button onClick={this.asyncStuff} asyncHandler="onClick"/>
</AsyncContainer>
```

The asyncHandler property should be removed from the button before rendering.

AsyncContainer uses `React.cloneElement(child, properties)`.

I've tried nulling the asyncHandler property, setting it to undefined and deleting the property from the child.props. It seems that it is impossible to get rid of this property again.

Comment: `props` in React are immutable and thus cannot be changed by the component itself. The parent must modify the `prop` and then pass it down to the component.

Comment: You can't do anything with props in child, 'cause they are read-only: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only

Comment: Maybe you could clone the child and replace the property object somehow?

Comment: Does anybody know why they don't add a feature to remove some attributes of the props? SolidJS has `splitProps` which in my opinion is very useful.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this issue. You can just create a new element and use the old element's type and props you want to pass through. I'm not sure if this an anti-pattern or not, I just stumbled on it and it seems to be working well so far.

It should look something like this:

```
function AsyncContainer(props) {
  const child = React.Children.only(props.children)
  const { asyncHandler, ...childProps } = child.props
  // do asyncHandler stuff
  return React.createElement(child.type, childProps)
}
```

Comment: This works in many situations, but has a drawback. From the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement "... it also preserves refs. This means that if you get a child with a ref on it, you won’t accidentally steal it from your ancestor. You will get the same ref attached to your new element."

Answer (score 1):

```
function AsyncContainer(props) {
  const child = React.Children.only(props.children);
  return React.cloneElement(
    child,
    { asyncHandler: undefined }
  );
}
```

## How it works

1. You clone element using `React.cloneElement` because element is immutable and only way to change its props is to create clone.
2. Use second `React.cloneElement` argument to add new props and remove old props. Unneeded props should be assigned with `undefined`. You need to do this because by default cloned element is cloned with all its props.

Comment: This way the prop `asyncHandler` is set to `undefined`, but how to completely remove from the cloned component props?

Comment: Did you actually test this? I don't think you can use an undefined value like that to replace the function. I'd suggest looking at `React.createElement()`

Comment: This is a really good answer and it does not feel hacky either. Tested and it works - [test case in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-volhard-f6fm9b?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments you cannot modify the props directly as they are immutable.

However, I think I have a simple solution to this problem. I have no idea what library that is or how it works, so ***this may or may not work***. However, this is a general answer to how you would remove a prop before a component gets mounted.

That being said, I would try to create my own component which renders a `<Button />`:

```
class MyButtonComponent extends React.Component {

...

  render() {
    return <Button onClick={this.props.onClickHandler} />;
  }
}
```

Then in the component you want to do your enhancements:

```
render() {
  <AsyncContainer>
    <MyButtonComponent onClickHandler={this.asyncStuff} asyncHandler="onClick"/>
  </AsyncContainer>
}
```

This way you maintain your `onClick` eventlistener on the `<Button />` component but you don't pass the illegal `asyncHandler` prop.

---

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you could also do:

```
class MyButtonComponent extends React.Component {

...

  componentWillMount() {
    let newProps = this.props;
    delete newProps.asyncHandler;
    this.setState({properties: newProps}):
  }

  render() {
    return <Button {...this.state.properties} />;
  }
}
```

This will apply all the props (with the [**spread operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)) to `<Button />` except for `asyncHandler` which we delete prior to the component being mounted by creating a copy of the `props` in `state` but with `asyncHandler` removed.

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40280490/2030321) I gave to a similar question.