# Remove a prop from cloned React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal: I need to perform some post-processing of React components, and that involves removing some props. I tried to use [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) passing `{propToRemove: undefined}` as the second argument, but the prop is not removed, just set to `undefined`. I could use [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createElement), but according to the docs, that would lose `ref`s, which is a serious drawback.

A contrived example not doing anything useful, just to test:

```
const removeUnknownPropWithClone = (el) => {
  return React.cloneElement(el, {unknownProp: undefined})
};

const App = (props) => 
  removeUnknownPropWithClone(
    <div unknownProp="1">Hello</div>
  );
```

This shows the error message: "React does not recognize the `unknownProp` prop on a DOM element". Indeed, the prop is set to `undefined`, but it's still there. I need to completely remove it.

[Runnable snippet](https://repl.it/@tokland/ReactRemovePropsFromClonedComponent) (open the console to see the error messages)

Related question (but not answered there): [React - Remove prop from child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43041013/react-remove-prop-from-child)

Relevant source code: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L293

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43041013/react-remove-prop-from-child to see if you can find a few inspiration?

Comment: Thanks, @DamianSimonPeter, I did, even wrote a couple of comments :)

Comment: Yeah, I think the error seems kinda straightforward I may be wrong. You shouldn't have "unknownProp=1" in a DOM element. I guess this is the cause of your error `<div unknownProp="1"`
@tokland

Comment: Yeah, of course, it's a contrived example, I'll add a note to the question. I want the processing to remove the prop, which is being used somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's good to look at sources ;)

`cloneElement` doesn't let remove prop - they are copied and overwritten. No option for deleting or passing function.

But looking a bit higher we can see:

```
export function cloneAndReplaceKey(oldElement, newKey) {
  const newElement = ReactElement(
    oldElement.type,
    newKey,
    oldElement.ref,
    oldElement._self,
    oldElement._source,
    oldElement._owner,
    oldElement.props,
  );

  return newElement;
}
```

Looks easy to extend but ReactElement isn't exported :]

... but it looks like `ref`, `key` and trimmed props can be copied/passed (by config) to `createElement`. Check if it will be sufficient.

Comment: I did check, here: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L293. I saw no way to remove a prop, thus the question. I'll check with manual manipulation of ref/key, even though that's what I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 5):

Very simple with JSX (inside a `Children.map()` function):

```
const { filtered, ...rest } = child.props
const clone = <child.type key={child.key} ref={child.ref} {...rest} />
```

Answer (score 2):

We solved it this way

```
const { propToRemove, ...childProps } = child.props
const filteredChild = { ...child, props: childProps }

return React.cloneElement(filteredChild, additionalProps)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could copy the element props to another object and delete the undesired prop in the new object

```
const removeUnknownPropWithClone = (el) => {
  const props = { ...el.props }
  delete props['unknownProps']
  return React.cloneElement(el, props)
};
```

Comment: Props passed to cloneElement are merged into el.props, so `unknownProp` will still be there.